# How to enable Electron to use chrome://flags/#enable-force-dark

Tags: google-chrome, electron, chromium

We found the chrome flag chrome://flags/#enable-force-dark that forces all websites to use dark mode and it's quite nice actually!

We cannot get this flag to work in Electron, however. Here's what we tried:

```
app.commandLine.appendSwitch('enable-force-dark');
app.commandLine.appendSwitch('force-dark-mode');
app.commandLine.appendSwitch('enable-features', 'enableForceDark');
app.commandLine.appendSwitch('enable-features', 'WebUIDarkMode');
```

Sadly, none of them work. Any pointers would be appreciated.

Comment: Those features are part of Chromium browser, not Blink or v8. That's why they are not available in Electron.

Comment: Ah good to know for the future, thanks for the note

Comment: I'm not quite sure if reasoning given in the above comment is entirely accurate, since Electron embeds parts of Chromium rather than Blink or V8 directly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [Electron docs](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/command-line-switches) specify a list of supported command line switches (some of which do come from Chromium). Unfortunately, `--enable-force-dark` is not on that list.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Hopefully it will come soon a lot of our users are craving that dark mode!

Answer (score 1):

That's because it should be:

```
app.commandLine.appendSwitch('enable-features', 'WebContentsForceDark');
```

You can find it out by enabling it and going to `chrome://version` and looking at the command line.

However in this case you should use [`themeSource`](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/native-theme#nativethemethemesource) instead.

Edit: Actually I guess that isn't the same as forcing dark mode (not sure you should do that) but if you want to I think maybe you're meant to do this instead:

```
    new BrowserWindow({
      webPreferences: {
        enableBlinkFeatures: "WebContentsForceDark",
      },
      ...
```

I haven't tried it though, and it seems to be hella janky. I can't make it work through any method for `CSSColorSchemeUARendering`.